# Trouble with Xfce permissions for suspend and nm-applet

Tags: debian, permissions, xfce, networkmanager, suspend

I have problems with permissions in Xfce, and I have no idea how to search for solutions.

Googling gives lots of different solutions but none of them work for me.

When I suspend/logout/reboot etc I get a dialogue asking me for my password.

Lots of options in the network management applet are grayed out.

I suspect the two problems are related. The problems showed up after upgrading some packages a few weeks ago.

I'm using Debian testing and Xfce. The system was installed with the Debian installer and worked fine up until recently.